# How to change background image on click with animation using jquery and css

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

How to change the background image of a block
I have four buttons- pressing one button should change the background image with animation like (Fadein or fadeout). 
I have used this code its changing the background but how to add animation.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

$('#i1').on({
     'click': function(){
         $('#change-image').css("background-image", "url('../Zelos/img/e1.jpg')");
     }
 });

$('#i2').on({
     'click': function(){
         $('#change-image').css("background-image", "url('../Zelos/img/e2.jpg')");

     }
 });

$('#i3').on({
     'click': function(){
         $('#change-image').css("background-image", "url('../Zelos/img/e3.jpg')");
     }
 });

$('#i4').on({
     'click': function(){
         $('#change-image').css("background-image", "url('../Zelos/img/e4.jpg')");
     }
 });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with the transition style rule, for example: `transition: all .6s ease-in`

```js
$('#i1').on({
  'click': function() {
    $('#change-image').css("background-image", "url(http://placekitten.com/1500/1500)");
  }
});

$('#i2').on({
  'click': function() {
    $('#change-image').css("background-image", "url(http://placekitten.com/1200/1200)");

  }
});

$('#i3').on({
  'click': function() {
    $('#change-image').css("background-image", "url(http://placekitten.com/1400/1400)");
  }
});

$('#i4').on({
  'click': function() {
    $('#change-image').css("background-image", "url(http://placekitten.com/1000/1000)");
  }
});
```

```css
#change-image{
   background: url(http://placekitten.com/500/500) center/cover;
   height: 300px;
   width: 300px;
   transition: all .6s ease-in;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="i1">Click Me 1</button>
<button id="i2">Click Me 2</button>
<button id="i3">Click Me 3</button>
<button id="i4">Click Me 4</button>

<div id="change-image"></div>
```